# Tamanho da Imagem Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, imagem, div

Boa noite galera, estou com um problema em javascript que é o seguinte:

Eu preciso criar div dinamicamente em um `for` e colocar nessas divs uma imagem, consegui fazer isso com o seguinte código:

```
for(y = 0;y<z;y++){
         passarImagem[y] = document.createElement("div");

         var testando = document.createElement("img");
         testando = "<img src=exemmplo.png>";
         testando.width = 500;
          testando.height = 500;

         passarImagem[y].innerHTML = testando.src;
     }
```

Preciso dimensionar essas imagens para um tamanho especifico, coloquei como exemplo 500, porém dessa maneira que fiz não funciona, gostaria de saber se possui uma maneira de alterar o tamanho dessa imagem.

Answer (score 3):

Aqui está um exemplo utilizando `appendChild()`, que nada mais é do que criar um "filho" para um "pai", onde cada elemento `<img>` é um filho e a div principal o pai:

```js
for(y = 0; y < 10; y++){
  principal = document.getElementById("principal");
  
  var imagem = document.createElement("img");
  
  imagem.src = "https://i.imgur.com/F543MoZ.png";
  imagem.width = 30;
  imagem.height = 30;

  principal.appendChild(imagem);
}
```

```html
<div id="principal"></div>
```